# SQL Server Simple Query Joining Table With Itself

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `GAMES` which holds data about past games played. The point of this query is to find all the games that have been played on the same date and print the date, the two teams that played and the result. The table is set up like this:

**GAMES**

```
Home   | Visitors|Date      |Result
-------------------------------------
Bengals| Browns  | 1/1/2012 | Tie
Browns | Bengals | 1/1/2012 | Loss
Giants | Jets    | 4/2/2013 | Win
Giants | Cowboys | 4/2/2013 | Loss
Bears  | Ravens  | 5/3/2012 | Tie
Bills  | Dolphins| 10/11/2014| Win
...
```

I think the solution is to join the tables in a query similar to this

```
select 
    A.Date, A.Home, A.Visitors, A.Result
from 
    GAMES as A, GAMES as B
where 
    A.Date = B.Date 
    and A.Home = B.Visitors;
```

but in this specific query it will only return one game first of all, there are 6 games in total that should show up, and only returns the values from Table A. Is there a way in which I can write the query so it finds all games at once rather than tailoring a specific query to find each one? Thanks.

Desired results would be in the form of:

```
1 2012-1-1 Bengals Browns Tie
2 2012-1-1 Browns Bengals Loss
3 2013-4-2 Giants Jets Win
4 2013-4-2 Giants Cowboys Loss
etc.
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your desired results?   Your sample data is pretty confusing.

Comment: i edited it to include that

Comment: If your output is just the same as your existing data set then just order by the date...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT
    A.Date, A.Home, A.Visitors, A.Result
FROM 
    GAMES as A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM GAMES as B 
              WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE 
                AND (A.Home <> B.Home 
                OR   A.Visitors <> B.Visitors))
ORDER by A.Date ASC
```

Comment: this ended up working with a slight tweak so it grabs all the correct info, thanks:  WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE 
                AND (A.Home <> B.Home 
     OR A.Visitors <> B.Visitors))

Comment: I've updated the code sample to match your tweaks. Glad I could help -- enjoy your SQLing! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so sound like what you're trying to do is find dates where more than one game occurred. In that case

```
SELECT a.Date, count(*) as CountOfDate
FROM GAMES a
GROUP BY a.Date
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: thanks, i guess i was a little ambiguous with my data however. Not every game in the table will have a date that matches up with another one. in fact, most dates only have one game played on them that is why I am trying to find the dates which have two games. I edited the table to look a little closer to reality.